# ad hoc build not installing on ios 5.1

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am trying to install an ad hoc build for the iPad and it won't install. It does install on my iPad with iOS 5.0, so I know that it isn't a certificate problem. I just can't seem to figure why it wouldn't install on a device from ad hoc install via Safari

Comment: Are you installing on different iPads? If so are you sure the other iPad is in the provisioning profile?

Comment: And under build settings > base sdk it says iOS 5.1?

Comment: I tried that it, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution. I needed to go to Edit scheme->archive then set Build Configuration to Release

Answer (score 0):

I have had this happen as I use many different machines to build multiple projects and multiple devices to test.

You have said that your iPad is running iOS 5.0 but you are building an adhoc build for base SDK 5.1.  The XCode tools dont allow your test device not to match exactly the base SDK you are developing for.

You either need to update your iPad to 5.1 or downgrade your base SDK to 5.0.  I would recommend simply upgrading your iPad!!!

Comment: It installs on the iPad with iOS 5.0. It doesn't install on the iPads with iOS 5.1